# Select2 add a new value to the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i have read a lot of posts about this option: adding a new value to a select2 list, but all i tried don't work. Here is my code:

```
$('#profession').select2({
    tags: true,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    placeholder: 'Search for a profession',
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function () {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return { id: term, text: term };
        }
    },
    createTag: function (params) {
        return {
            id: params.term,
            text: params.term,
            newOption: true
        }
    },
    templateResult: function (data) {
        var $result = $("<span></span>");

        $result.text(data.text);

        if (data.newOption) {
            $result.append(" <em>(new)</em>");
        }

        return $result;
    },
    ajax: {
        url: root_url + "profession/listProfession",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {  return { results: data.results} },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

When i type "Plu", select2 display Plumber and i can add Plumbers1234 (for example) but if i type "BLABLA" (i have no profession begin by BLA) i can't add the value BLABLA. And i don't understand why. The select2 field is in a bootstrap modal, i retired le tabindex attribut.

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

I tried to retire ajax part. Without ajax, i can type a value and select it. But i load data from ajax. Here is the code:

```
$('#profession').select2({
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (params) {
        return {
            id: params.term,
            text: params.term,
            newOption: true
        }
    },
    templateResult: function (data) {
        var $result = $("<span></span>");

        $result.text(data.text);

        if (data.newOption) {
            $result.append(" <em>(new)</em>");
        }

        return $result;
    }
});
```

How can i mix theses 2 codes together please ?

Comment: Anybody for an answer? Can i add some informations to help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="profession" id="profession" style="width:100%">
<?php foreach ($listProfession as $lp): ?>
     <option value="<?= $lp['profession_name']; ?>"><?= $lp['profession_name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

In my JS i only do:

```
// Initialisation du champ profession
$('#profession').select2({
    tags: true
});
```

And when i submit my form, i check in my database if the profession exist, if not, i add it in the db.

SOLVED!